# click a link with angularjs not responding to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to click a link with angularjs but it is not responding to click events when clicked. On clicking the anchor link nothing happens. This is the snippet of the angularjs script tag

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("module",[])
.controller("controller",function($scope){

  $scope.func =function(){
    alert('clicked me');
  }

})</script>
```

I am applying the click this way but it is not responding to click events

```
<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller" class="separator clear-left">
    <p class="btn-add">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <a href="#" id="click" class="hidden-sm add" id-data="1">Add to cart</a>
        <br>
        <a ng-click="func()" href="#">Take me there</a> <!-- area of problem -->
    </p>
    <p class="btn-details">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm detail">More details</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Why is click event not happening using angularjs

Comment: try console.log. If console.log shows value, check whether alert is blocked on the window. @parker

Comment: May be your css override. check your button css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above cord works without any issue. Probably you can compare and see

**Demo**

```js
  angular.module("module",[])
.controller("controller",function($scope){

  $scope.func =function(){
    alert('clicked me');
  }

})
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller" class="separator clear-left">
    <p class="btn-add">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <a href="#" id="click" class="hidden-sm add" id-data="1">Add to cart</a>
        <br>
        <a ng-click="func()" href="#">Take me there</a> <!-- area of problem -->
    </p>
    <p class="btn-details">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm detail">More details</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: on adding it to the page the link is crayed out dont know if a script is preventing it from been clickable

Comment: @parker adding to which page?

Comment: lets initialize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141421/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-parker).

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a jsbin. It works
https://jsbin.com/hifujod/edit?html,js,console,output

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller" class="separator clear-left">
    <p class="btn-add">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <a href="#" id="click" class="hidden-sm add" id-data="1">Add to cart</a>
        <br>
        <a ng-click="func()" href="#">Take me there</a> <!-- area of problem -->
    </p>
    <p class="btn-details">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm detail">More details</a>
    </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
 angular.module("module",[])
.controller("controller",function($scope){

  $scope.func =function(){
    alert('clicked me');

  }
 })
```

Comment: on adding it the page the link is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine.Check your css because may be css override the element.

```js
angular.module("mainApp",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.func =function(){
    console.log('Hi!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="ctrl" class="separator clear-left">
    <p class="btn-add">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <a href="#" id="click" class="hidden-sm add" id-data="1">Add to cart</a>    
   <a ng-click="func()" href="#">Take me there</a>
    </p>
    <p class="btn-details">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm detail">More details</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How can u use css to prevent overrding

Comment: just inspect and check it. Weather any element is override or not.

Comment: first remove related css class and check click fuc

Answer (score -2):

Modify the line below as mentioned here and give a try

```
<a ng-click="func()" href="">Take me there</a>
```